Have you ever purchased an InDesign template?
Have you ever purchased an InDesign template? If so, would you be willing to share what type of template and what was the project? If you ever felt the need to purchase a template, not because they lack skills, but for other reasons, whether it’s for a client project or a personal passion project. This is for a research project. Thank You!

I don't think this question fits a Q&A site because it has no possible resolution and therefore not worth answering
